# change color of tab bar controller using storyboard

Tags: colors, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I am working on Storyboard  and have added Tabbar Controller in it.I want to change the color of Tabbar to green or yellow.Is there any way i can change it ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I do it, hope this help [image]